# Combobox displays repeated items in C#

Tags: c#, combobox, bindingsource

I have two ComboBoxes in my form. When any item of the first ComboBox is selected the 2nd ComboBox is updated. Let's say the 1st CB is Country and the 2nd is Cities of that Country.

I used the code below to filter the bindingSource of the 2nd CB (City):

```
cityTblBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("CountryID = {0}", CustomerCountryID);
```

Surprisingly it works for some countries. But for some countries there will be repeated cities.

Example(Fine):
Country = Iran  =>  Cities = Isfehan, Tehran, Yazd

Example(Problematic):
Country = Germany  =>  Cities = Munich, Berlin, Munich, Berlin

How can I get rid of the repeated items?

Comment: This seems not possible given the same logical filter unless there is something very wrong in your data or in the code that loads that data

Comment: Try modifying your select statement for initially querying the database to select distinct city names, then the filter should work how it is.

Comment: I am really sorry to ask the question before checking my data. The problem is with my City Table. ( ._.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using linq on your datasource it would avoid to alter your original datasource.

```
 List<Cities> cities = (List<Cities>)cityTblBindingSource.DataSource;
 cityTblBindingSource.DataSource = cities.Where(x=>x.CountryID == CustomerCountryID).Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. But as I said my database had duplicate items which I was not aware of. Thank you anyway. :)